Rank of the matrix made by the diagonal components of the exponential matrix of the block diagonal matrix
I define the $9 \times 9$ matrix $\bf{K}$ as
$${\bf K}=\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
\bf{A} & p\bf{I} & \bf{O} \\
p\bf{I} & \bf{B} & q\bf{I} \\ 
\bf{O} & q\bf{I} & \bf{C} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
where $3 \times 3$ matrices ${\bf A},{\bf B}$ and ${\bf C}$ are defined as
$${\bf A}={\rm diag}(x_1,x_2,x_3), \\
{\bf B}=b{\bf I} + {\bf A}, \\
{\bf C}=c{\bf I} + {\bf A},
$$
for real numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,b,c,p$ and $q$. I also define $3 \times 3$ matrix $\bf{U}$ as
$$\bf{U}=\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf K}_{11} & {\bf K}_{44} & {\bf K}_{77} \\
{\bf K}_{22} & {\bf K}_{55} & {\bf K}_{88} \\ 
{\bf K}_{33} & {\bf K}_{66} & {\bf K}_{99} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
As I see in numerical simulation, the matrix rank of ${\bf U}$ seem to be always $1$. But I cannot prove it mathematically. How can I do that?

+1 for all bold :)

thanks. I like the bold style for matrices.

That's  bold statement.

Mathematica will compute this stuff in fractions of a second.

Hint: up to a permutation, it is a block diaginal matrix where the difference between the blocks are multiples of identity. I bet that the rows of U are proportional to $e^{x_i}$

@Abezhiko Thank you for the suggestion. I do not have a mathematica.

@Exodd  The matrix $A$ is diagonal but not scalar; in consequence, $A-pI$ is not a multiple of identity for instance.

@Abezhiko in fact you have first to permute the rows and columns

For a certain permutation matrix ${\bf P}$ you get
$${\bf P}{\bf K}{\bf P}^T=\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf Y} & \bf{O} & \bf{O} \\
\bf{O} & {\bf Y} + (x_2-x_1)\bf{I} & \bf{O} \\ 
\bf{O} & \bf{O} & {\bf Y} +  (x_3-x_1)\bf{I} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\right)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\exp({\bf Y}) & \bf{O} & \bf{O} \\
\bf{O} & \exp({\bf Y} + (x_2-x_1)\bf{I}) & \bf{O} \\ 
\bf{O} & \bf{O} & \exp({\bf Y} +  (x_3-x_1)\bf{I}) \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\exp({\bf Y}) & \bf{O} & \bf{O} \\
\bf{O} & \exp(x_2-x_1)\exp({\bf Y}) & \bf{O} \\ 
\bf{O} & \bf{O} & \exp(x_3-x_1)\exp({\bf Y}) \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
{\bf Y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & p & 0 \\
p & x_1+b & q \\ 
0& q& x_1+c \\ 
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad {\bf Z}:= \exp({\bf Y}).
$$
As a consequence,
$$
\bf{U}=\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf Z}_{11} & {\bf Z}_{22} & {\bf Z}_{33} \\
\exp(x_2-x_1){\bf Z}_{11} & \exp(x_2-x_1){\bf Z}_{22} & \exp(x_2-x_1){\bf Z}_{33} \\ 
\exp(x_3-x_1){\bf Z}_{11} & \exp(x_3-x_1){\bf Z}_{22} & \exp(x_3-x_1){\bf Z}_{33} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that has always rank exactly 1 since the diagonal of ${\bf Z}$ cannot be zero.
